# .net add existing project to docker container

Tags: .net, docker

I have a question.

I have a Blazor (wasm and c#) project in .net5 in container in docker, but now I want to use already existing project as reference to this project.

Problem is I do not know hot to bite this, should I make another container for each already existing project (existing project are not containers), or should somehow copy this project to container. And if so external projects will be updated in non docker environment, so maybe there is possibility to link it to container to use it.

I hope I have explained my problem. And what should I do or use to achieve my goal?

Comment: A container is how you deploy the compiled and published executable. It doesn't affect the existing project, solution or source code.

Comment: Hi, you can deploy all your codes and packages that you need in  your first docker container and for the next projects if you need that source again you can build an image from it and for the next project use `FROM SourceImage:v0.01` in your DockerFile for example if in your first DockerFile is `FROM ubuntu` as source image now you can use your own docker source image with all things you have been done in your last previous project